# "Terminated due to timeout"

Tags: c++

How do i make my code more efficient, I'm getting a "Terminated due to timeout" on Hackerrank.
Please suggest changes I should be making to avoid this error.

Also, is it the nested for loop that is somewhat causing this problem?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

     int  n,k;
     cin>>n>>k;

     int **arr = new int*[n]();

     for (long i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
         arr[i] = new int[n]();
    }
     for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
         int b;
         cin>>b;

         for(int j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
              cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
     for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<arr[a][b]<<endl;        
    }  


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<<endl; ` may cause you the timeout because you are flushing the stream at every output.

Comment: `cout` is also slower than `printf`. But with no description of the actual problem, it's impossible to know if your algorithm is poor.

Comment: ***But with no description of the actual problem, it's impossible to know if your algorithm is poor*** That is a very good point. Perhaps there is some wording in the question on the values of `a` and `b` that allow you to not even store the entire array.

Comment: @sweenish No it generally isn’t, that’s a myth.

Comment: @KonradRudolph https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#benchmarks

Comment: @sweenish Yes, I’m aware of this benchmark. It shows an area where fmtlib performance shines (complex format string/iomanip use) but it’s not representative of iostream performance. Other benchmarks show substantially different results. This particular benchmark almost certainly measures iomanip overhead, not iostreams overhead. And that’s fair, but irrelevant here.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, **T**ime **L**imit **E**xceeded errors are due to a slow algorithm; you should find a faster algorithm or implementation.  For example, try applying some algebra to simplify calculations; use `x * x` instead of `pow(x,2)`, etc.

Comment: For the third read, you may want to use block or bulk read, using the `istream::read` method.

Comment: You allocate memory for `n` elements but you write `b` elements into each row. This could be a huge problem. What if `b > n`? This would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: *"I'm getting a "Terminated due to timeout" on Hackerrank"* What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory for `n` elements in each row but you access `b` elements in each row. For `b < n` this could cost performance and for `b > n` this causes undefined behavior.

Also avoid the flush after each output.

`++i` can be faster and should never be slower than `i++`.

Remove unused headers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

     int  n,k;
     cin>>n>>k;

     int **arr = new int*[n]();

     for (long i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) // <-- ++i instead of i++
    {
         int b;
         cin>>b;
         arr[i] = new int[b](); // <-- allocate memory for b elements
         for(int j=0;j<b;++j) // <-- ++i instead of i++
        {
              cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
     for(int j=0;j<k;++j) // <-- ++i instead of i++
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<arr[a][b]<<'\n'; // <-- don't flush on each line break
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: “`++i` can be faster and should never be slower than `i++`.” — This is true in general but never for integers, and is irrelevant here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What is the intention of your comment? Should I remove the change and don't mention the fact, that `++i` is always at least as good as and in special cases better than `i++`? Is it really helpful to criticize such a habit? Probably you are right but I wouldn't waste a second thinking about it because `++i` will never be the wrong decision.

Comment: I think it’s helpful as a general comment but your answer makes it sound as if it might have an impact on OP’s specific code because the answer doesn’t explain *when/why* `++i` can be more efficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've learned that people which use `std::endl` in competitive programming don't want to know when/why to use `++i`. The main point of my answer is the possible undefined behavior. The preincrement is a side comment. I don't see the disadvantage of advising to use preincrement. OP shouldn't think about if it's necessary or helpful. Also I have to admit that I didn't know that it's guaranteed same behavior for primitives.